# error al almancenar la base datos en php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un error al compilar el codigo de php a mysql:

archivo de conexion con la base de datos:

```
    <?php

        $dbname = "hostienda_prueba";
        $user = "adrian";
        $password = "admin";
        $host = "localhost";

        $conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password,$dbname) or die ("no se pudo conectar a la base datos").mysqli_connect_error();
        mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
        echo " conexion exitosa.";

        ?>
```

parte de HTML5

```
      <title>caja de comentarios</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <table>
    <form action="datos.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <tr>
    <td><label for ="fecha">fecha:</label></td>
    <td><input type="date" name="fecha"></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

     <input name="Imagen" type="file" ><br/><br/>
    </tr>
    <td><label for ="hour">hora:</label></td>
    <td><input type="time" name="hora"><br></td>
    </tr>

    <td><label for="nombre">Nombre:</label></td>

    <td><input type="text" name="nombre"></td><br>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label for ="nombre">Comentario:</label></td>
    <td>
    <textarea type="text" name="comentario" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="enviar"></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
    </table>
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Parte lógica de ingreso de datos->

```
?php
include("conexion.php");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];


  //insercion de los datos
  $query = "INSERT in to comentarios(nombre,Imagen,comentario,fecha,hora) 
            VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen','$comentario','$fecha','$hora')";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

  if($resultado){
      echo " se inserto la base de datos";
  }else{
      echo " no se inserto la base de datos :/";
  }

}
```

el error que muestra al compilar

> conexion exitosa. Warning: mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away
>   in C:\xampp2\htdocs\hostienda\datos.php on line 13
>
> Warning: mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\hostienda\datos.php on line 13 no se inserto la base
>   de datos :/

he trato de varias formas pero no encuentro como solucionar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la parte lógica tienes un error de sintaxis en tu query para insertar pusiste **in to** en vez de **INTO** quitale el espacio y vuelve a intentar quedando el script de esta manera.

```
<?php
include("conexion.php");
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $Imagen = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['Imagen']['tmp_name']));
    $comentario = $_POST['comentario'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];


  //insercion de los datos
  $query = "INSERT into comentarios(nombre,Imagen,comentario,fecha,hora) 
            VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen','$comentario','$fecha','$hora')";
  $resultado = $conexion->query($query);

  if($resultado){
      echo " se inserto la base de datos";
  }else{
      echo " no se inserto la base de datos :/";
  }

}
?>
```

Comment: gracias amigo ya me pudo almacenar la base de datos con imagen y el comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Fijate que creo que tu codigo no está bien. La forma correcta sería:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO comentarios(nombre,Imagen,comentario,fecha,hora) 
            VALUES('$nombre','$Imagen','$comentario','$fecha','$hora')";
```

El error está en que escribiste "in to" en vez de "INTO".

Comment: Me volvio a tirar el mismo error ahora: Warning: mysqli::query(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp2\htdocs\hostienda\datos.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli::query(): Error reading result set's header in C:\xampp2\htdocs\hostienda\datos.php on line 13
no se inserto la base de datos :/ ya haviendo cambiando el into hoy